# How to clear input value after submit with LabelInput

Tags: react-native

I create a component as below.

It allows the user to input their id and submits it.

Now I want to clear the input value after submit.

How to implement?

```js
const InputUserModal = ({ onConfirm }) => {
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    useEffect(() => {
        register({ name: 'userId' }, { required: true });
    }, [register]);
    return (
      <View>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="userId"
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ onChange, value }) => (
              <LabelInput
                label='user'
                iconSetting={{
                    name: 'user',
                    type: 'feather',
                }}
                onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit(onConfirm)}
                autoFocus
                onChangeText={v => onChange(v)}
                value={value}
              />
            )}
          />
      </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Formik, It provides `reset` function, which you can pass as a reference in `onConfirm` as below:

```js
const InputUserModal = ({ onConfirm }) => {
    const { register, control, handleSubmit, errors,resetForm } = useForm();
    useEffect(() => {
        register({ name: 'userId' }, { required: true });
    }, [register]);
    return (
      <View>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="userId"
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ onChange, value }) => (
              <LabelInput
                label='user'
                iconSetting={{
                    name: 'user',
                    type: 'feather',
                }}
                onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit(onConfirm(values,resetForm)}
                autoFocus
                onChangeText={v => onChange(v)}
                value={value}
              />
            )}
          />
      </View>
    );
};
```

Assume that you render this component  as below

```js
const ParentComponent = ()=>{

    const handleOnConfirm =(values,resetForm)=>{

// Your function to submit  input  values to a server

// then  resetFormik Values

        resetForm()
    }

    return (
      <InputUserModal onConfirm={handleOnConfirm}/>
    )
}
```